# NullReferenceException on TitleResource for SPNavigationNode

Tags: development, quick-launch

I keep getting a `NullReferenceException` when trying to access the `TitleResource` of an `SPNavigationNode`.

```
bool isExternal = false;
// assume anything starting with "http" is an external link
if (url.StartsWith("http", true, WebSiteInfo.en)) isExternal = true;

SPNavigationNode entry = new SPNavigationNode(nameEn, url, isExternal);

SPUserResource _userResource = entry.TitleResource;
_userResource.SetValueForUICulture(WebSiteInfo.fr, nameFr);
_userResource.Update();

SPNavigationNodeCollection quickLaunch = web.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
quickLaunch.AddAsLast(entry);
```

Things work fine if I remove the attempt to set the alternate language title, but then of course I don't have multilingual support on my entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by trying to set the title resource too early. Apparently an SPNavigationNode is not fully instantiated until after adding it to a collection.

This code works

```
bool isExternal = false;
// assume anything starting with "http" is an external link
if (url.StartsWith("http", true, WebSiteInfo.en)) isExternal = true;

SPNavigationNode entry = new SPNavigationNode(nameEn, url, isExternal);

SPNavigationNodeCollection quickLaunch = web.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
quickLaunch.AddAsLast(entry);

SPUserResource _userResource = entry.TitleResource;
_userResource.SetValueForUICulture(WebSiteInfo.fr, nameFr);
_userResource.Update();
```